# Syntax of Slurm jobnames?

Tags: syntax, path, slurm

Does anyone know what the allowed syntax is for slurm jobnames (i.e. the argument to `sbatch -J`)? I can't find any documentation on this anywhere. It looks like slashes (`/`) in the name are not allowed, but they easily occur when passing a file path as an argument to my script that takes care of job submission. And there may well be more restrictions. Any pointer to the documentation would be appreciated (as would, BTW, a decent error message from `sbatch`, currently I just get exit code 1, nothing else).

Answer (score -1):

You can try with putting the job name under the string double quotes "".this might resolve your issue.

sbatch -J "name of your job"

sbatch --job-name "name of your job"

Comment: This unfortunately does not solve the slash problem.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong.  Both `sbatch` and `squeue` can accept slashes if quoted.